# sql procedure stores multiple records of the same

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, procedure

My sql server database has this stored procedure...

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewBudget]
@year int,
@int nvarchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT [NAOLI].[dbo].[BudgetsEditTbl]
([F_Year],[O_OrgCode],[O_OrgDesc],[S_SubObject],[S_SubDescrip],[B_BudgetAmt],[B_Initials],[B_CIPrefNo],[B_OrgBudgetAmt],[keyfield]) 
SELECT @year as [F_Year],[O_OrgCode],[O_OrgDesc],[S_SubObject],[S_SubDescrip], 0.00 as [B_BudgetAmt],@int as [B_Initials],null as [B_CIPrefNo],null as [B_OrgBudgetAmt],NewID()
FROM [NAOLI].[dbo].[BudgetsEditTbl]
END
```

What happends is according to the parameter '@year' it automatically updates the database with records for the new year on the year change. Only instead of updating it with the new year, the orgcode and the corresponding subobject it gives me 6 records with the same orgcode. So it is essentially running the procedure 6 times and storing all that mess in my database. Any idea how I can fix this problem?

```
2011 | 536003 | Engineering | 6302 | Roads and Components | 0.00 | MC | N/A | 0.00    
2011 | 536003 | Engineering | 6303 | Rights of Way -Acquire | 0.00 | MC | N/A | 0.00
2010 | 536003 | Engineering | 6302 | Roads and Components | 18300.00 | FG | N/A | 0.00    
2010 | 536003 | Engineering | 6303 | Rights of Way -Acquire | 18300.00 | FG | N/A | 0.00
```

So for each year the same codes and info go in just different amounts...

Comment: Now the query only returned onw record total

Comment: Are you trying to only copy the data from the previous year?

Comment: No there are 50 orgcodes and 25 sub objects I need it to take the year parameter lets say its "2025" and add a row to the database for each of the 50 orgcodes and thier corresponding sub objects so there should be a total of 1764 records for the year 2025 when were done. (25 for orgcode1, 25 for orgcode2, 25 for orgcode3... etc...)

Comment: I'm new to sql should it be DISTINCT[O_OrgCode], DISTINCT[O_OrgDesc] etc... ?

Comment: `DISTINCT` should be right after `SELECT`: `INSERT ... SELECT DISTINCT ...`. Try the select alone first, it will show you what will be inserted when you add `INSERT`

Comment: I've updated my answer below, are these org codes and sub objects stored in a different table?  It might be better to cross join those tables instead

Comment: @msmucker0527 FYI... Thanks for putting up with me I really appreciate the help and am thouroghly frustrated. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` to remove any duplicates

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[NewBudget]
@year int,
@int nvarchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT [NAOLI].[dbo].[BudgetsEditTbl]
([F_Year],[O_OrgCode],[O_OrgDesc],[S_SubObject],[S_SubDescrip],[B_BudgetAmt],[B_Initials],[B_CIPrefNo],[B_OrgBudgetAmt],[keyfield]) 
SELECT DISTINCT @year as [F_Year],[O_OrgCode],[O_OrgDesc],[S_SubObject],[S_SubDescrip], 0.00 as [B_BudgetAmt],@int as [B_Initials],null as [B_CIPrefNo],null as [B_OrgBudgetAmt],NewID()
FROM [NAOLI].[dbo].[BudgetsEditTbl]
END
```

Comment: This also only returns one record total

Comment: Used Distinct still only getting one row returned... Let me post what some of the info is supposed to look like.

Comment: Well if they're not in the table that you're selecting from already... then you're going about this all wrong

Comment: they o_orgcode, o_orgdesc, s_subobject, s_subdescrip are all already in the table just for previous years... I need it to create those rows with amounts $0.00 for the next year...

Comment: `DISTINCT` should work then, make sure you removed the `TOP 1`

Comment: It doesn't and I'm not sure why... but thank you for all your help... It only returns one record total...